# javascript scroll to parent over http and https using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I have a secure (https) iFrame within a non-secure (http) page. When the user clicks on link in the iFrame, a new iFrame page loads.

However, because the first iFrame page is quite long, when it moves to the next page the parent page is still scrolled to the bottom. I use the code-

```
parent.scrollTo(0,0);
```

and it works, but not when the iFrame page is running over https.

I get the error (Firefox)-
*Permission denied for https://www.example.com to get property Window.scrollTo from http://www.example.com*

I think this is to stop xss attacks. I'm sure I've done a workaround to this before in javascript? Or is there a way I can set "allowed domains" on the parent page?

Comment: If you own the secure site in the iframe you can put a `window.scrollTo(0,0)` directly into that.

Comment: Secure and non-secure pages can't mess with eachother, regardless of their domains.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting this in the container page-

```
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#iframe').load(function(){
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
 });
});
```